# Stability of a pile of dominoes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, statics

[image]

Consider the above figure; $n$ identical uniform dominoes, each of length $l$, are stacked upon each other in the presence of a uniform gravitational field. Find the maximum distance and the setup for which the overhang of the topmost domino with respect to the bottom-most domino is maximum. You may regularly or irregularly place them on one another. Also, investigate the case in which the gravitational field is varying linearly from the bottom as $g=\alpha y+\beta$

Intuitively, it seems as though the stability of this system will be at the tipping edge when the center of gravity (or mass in case of a uniform gravitational field) of the $k$th domino from the bottom lies at the edge of the $(k-1)$th domino but I have no way of justifying this. Am I correct? If so, does anyone have a good argument for why I am correct? And, I haven't ever used the idea of a center of gravity in a variable gravitational field to determine the stability of a system so I would appreciate some help understanding that as well!

Comment: [Theory of corbelling](https://thestonetrust.org/master-class-masterclass-theory-of-corbelling/) and [Maximum overhang](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/papers/maxover.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!